# model values are not coming in response , why empty response in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, model, json

```
    public function ws_getPunchForApp($custid,$page=1,$size=10){

    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        }
        else{
            $res["error"] = "Invalid request";
            return $res;
        }

        $res = $punchCollection = array();
        $res = array();

        $custoid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();

        if($custoid == $custid)
        {   $current = date('Y-m-d');
            //$custid= Mage::getModel('manager/asmtracker')->load($punch->getManagerId());

            $PunchData = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->getCollection()
                                                          //   ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('manager_id', array('eq' => $custid))
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('punch_in_time', array('eq' => $intime))
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('punch_out_time', array('eq' => $outtime))
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('in_coordinates', array('eq' => $outlocation))
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('out_coordinates', array('eq' => $intime))
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => $punchstatus))
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('create_at', array('eq' =>$current));




            $PunchData->setCurPage($page)->setPageSize($size);
            $totalPage = $PunchData->getLastPageNumber();


            print_r($PunchData);
//echo json_encode($PunchData);
            if(!empty($PunchData))
            {
                $i=0;
                foreach ($PunchData as $punch) 
                {   
             $custid= Mage::getModel('manager/asmtracker')->load($punch->getManagerId())->getData();
                  $punchCollection[$i]['manager_id'] = $custid;

             $intime = Mage::getModel('manager/asmtracker')->load($punch->getPunchInTime())->getData();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['punch_in_time'] =$intime;

             $outtime = Mage::getModel('manager/asmtracker')->load($punch->getPunchOutTime())->getData();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['punch_out_time'] =$outtime;

             $inlocation = Mage::getModel('manager/asmtracker')->load($punch->getInCoordinates())->getData();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['in_coordinates'] =$inlocation;

             $outlocation = Mage::getModel('manager/asmtracker')->load($punch->getOutCoordinates())->getData();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['out_coordinates']   = $outlocation;

             $punchstatus = Mage::getModel('manager/asmtracker')->load($punch->getStatus())->getData();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['status'] =$punchstatus;

             $create_at = Mage::getModel('manager/asmtracker')->load($punch->getCreateAt())->getData();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['create_at'] =$punch->getCreateAt();
                    ++$i;
                }
                $res['code'] = 200;
                $res['punchdata'] = $punchCollection;
                $res['totalpage'] = $totalPage;

            }else
            {

                  $res['code'] = 200;
                  $res['asmtracker'] = 'ok'; 
            }
        }else
        {
            $res['code'] =400;
            $res['msg'] ='Unable to process your request...';
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: You are calling for `->getFirstItem();` and then setting current page and size?? what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: many variables are undefine

Comment: i want to send values per page , what page is requested . can you help me out?

Comment: first of all define your variable like $intime $outtime and all

Comment: I have updated is it the correct way plz look !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function ws_getPunchForApp($custid,$page=1,$size=2){

    if(! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            $res["error"] = "Invalid request";
            return $res;
        }

        $res = $punchCollection = array();

        $custoid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();

        if($custoid == $custid)
        {  
            $current = date('Y-m-d');
            $PunchData = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->getCollection()
              ->setPageSize($size)
              ->setCurPage($page);

            if($PunchData->count()>0)
            {
              $i=0
                foreach ($PunchData as $punchstatus) 
                {
                    $punchCollection=array()
                    $punchCollection[$i]['manager_id'] = $punch->getManagerId();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['punch_in_time'] = $punch->getPunchInTime();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['punch_out_time'] = $punch->getPunchOutTime();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['in_coordinates'] = $punch->getInCoordinates();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['out_coordinates']   = $punch->getOutCoordinates();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['status'] = $punch->getStatus();
                    $punchCollection[$i]['create_at'] = $punch->getCreateAt();
                    $i++;
                }
                $res['code'] = 200;
                $res['punchdata'] = $punchCollection;
                $res['totalpage'] = $PunchData->count();

            }else
            {

                  $res['code'] = 200;
                  $res['asmtracker'] = 'ok'; 
            }
        }else
        {
            $res['code'] =400;
            $res['msg'] ='Unable to process your request...';
        }
        return $res;
}
```